# Git Gui- Cannot merge local

Tags: git, merge, git-gui

I'm trying to merge local, but I get this message:

**"You are in the middle of a change.**

**File .npmignore is modified.**

**You should complete the current commit before starting a merge.
Doing so will help you abort a failed merge, should the need arise."**

Searched for this message around internet but no good answers. 
I didn't do any code change yet. And I need to get the latest version of repository code.

How can I get ride of this message and why it is caused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to go to Merge Menu >> "Abort Merge..." before, to discard all your local changes.